# Calculate DAU/MAU from mongodb events

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, analytics

Here's what it looks like so far:

```
  collection.aggregate(
    [
      {
        $match: {
          ct: {$gte: dateFrom, $lt: dateTo },
        }
      },
      {
        $group: { 
          _id: '$user'
        }
      }
    ]
  ).toArray((err, result) => {
    callback(err, result.length)
  });
```

This gets me a list of users like this which I can count for DAU/MAU:

But I think this is not efficient, what's the correct way of doing this?

Comment: I guess you should ask that question here on code review: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use below aggregation for unique active users over day and month wise. I've assumed ct as timestamp field.

```
db.collection.aggregate(
[
  {"$match":{"ct":{"$gte":dateFrom,"$lt":dateTo}}},
  {"$facet":{
    "dau":[
      {"$group":{
        "_id":{
          "user":"$user",
          "ymd":{"$dateToString":{"format":"%Y-%m-%d","date":"$ct"}}
        }
      }},
      {"$group":{"_id":"$_id.ymd","dau":{"$sum":1}}}
    ],
    "mau":[
      {"$group":{
        "_id":{
          "user":"$user",
          "ym":{"$dateToString":{"format":"%Y-%m","date":"$ct"}}
        }
      }},
      {"$group":{"_id":"$_id.ym","mau":{"$sum":1}}}
    ]
  }}
])
```

DAU

```
db.collection.aggregate(
[
  {"$match":{"ct":{"$gte":dateFrom,"$lt":dateTo}}},
  {"$group":{
     "_id":{
        "user":"$user",
        "ymd":{"$dateToString":{"format":"%Y-%m-%d","date":"$ct"}}
      }
   }},
   {"$group":{"_id":"$_id.ymd","dau":{"$sum":1}}}
])
```

MAU

```
db.collection.aggregate(
[
  {"$match":{"ct":{"$gte":dateFrom,"$lt":dateTo}}},
  {"$group":{
     "_id":{
       "user":"$user",
       "ym":{"$dateToString":{"format":"%Y-%m","date":"$ct"}}
     }
  }},
  {"$group":{"_id":"$_id.ym","mau":{"$sum":1}}}
])
```

Comment: Hi can you explain why this solution is better or worse than my current or the distinct in the other answer?

Comment: I'm actually not trying to get the DAU/MAU both in 1 query, the flexible solution in my question where you pass in the date is the style I'm looking for.

Comment: It depends on what you are looking for. For example what is the date range ?  is it daily range, monthly range or custom range ?  My answer accounts for all time ranges, unique users activity and gives you the dau and mau across the time range. It is efficient in case you are looking over a time range. Sorry I don't understand what you refer my flexible solution as my answer also accepts the date like yours.

Comment: Sorry I guess I didn't understand your query. If I only want the DAU or the MAU does the $facet do more work than is required? But the question about the distinct is the more important one I think.

Comment: Np. It is indeed distinct as we group by `"user":"$user",` for both mau and dau. Right now it calculates both. I can split the query into 2 if you need only dau or mau. It is simply extracting the query out of facet and run it standalone.

Comment: Updated the answer now with two queries.

Comment: Thanks, though when I refer to distinct I'm talking about the answer by Romain Simon where he doesn't use aggregate at all. At first glance it seems simpler than using aggregate.

Comment: Np - It depends - if you only ever need to get dau for one single day or single month (  date range of single day vs month range )  it (Romain Simon solution ) will work perfectly. What about if you like to do this for multiple days or multiple months ? This is where aggregation comes in  to group them by day or month and this is what I thought you were asking.

Comment: Do you mean multiple non-contiguous days/months? I don't see any problems with doing multiples with Romain's solution.

Comment: I mean for example how do you calculate dau for let’s say today and tomorrow - with Romain’s solution it’s all days there is no grouping. You have to run the distinct query multiple times one for today’s and one for tomorrow’s. Aggregate is better as oppose to running same query multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

I made a quick test on a large database of events, and counting with a distinct is much faster than an aggregate if you have the right indexes :

```
collection.distinct('user', { ct: { $gte: dateFrom, $lt: dateTo } }).length
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use sum at the time of group.

```
collection.aggregate([
    { $match: {'date': {$gte: dateFrom, $lt: dateTo }}}, // fetch all requests from/to 
    { $group: { _id: '$user', total: { $sum: 1 }}}, // group all requests by user and sum the count of collection for a group
    { $sort: { total: -1 }}
  ], function (err, result) {
      if (err) cb(err, null);
      cb(null, result);
  });
```